# How critical is the accuracy of a fitness calculation in a genetic algorithm? Will inaccuracies work their way out over time?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm

Consider a genetic algorithm where fitness is a function of how many times a thing is "liked" ala Facebook.

Let's assume that some percentage of the time, likes originate due to factors beyond the strength of the content, and thus, the fitness of one chromosome vs. another is due in some part to random chance. Let's ballpark that number at 30% -- that is, 30% of the likes of any given thing are not due to deliberate action.

If we have 100 chromosomes, and we know our average conversion for a like is 5% (likes / impressions), how many impressions do we need to have to feel confident in the fitness rankings of each individual chromosome?

Comment: In my opinion this is always problem-/data-dependent. I also consider GA-based algorithms as one the least-theoretically driven approaches of learning (making it hard to analyze questions like these; but that's just my opinion). While noise is typically bad in convex-optimization, it might sometimes even help in non-convex optimization problems; e.g. leaving a local-optimum (comparable with stochastic gradient descent and it's batch-size).

Answer (score 0):

Optimising the wrong thing is a pretty good way of getting a wrong answer, and optimisation when you only have a noisy version of the evaluation function is different. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation. Even supposing that you find a plausible answer, you need to consider how sensitive that answer is to noise.